# Adding ODBC to MAMP

Tags: php, odbc, mamp

I've spent the last couple days trying to get ODBC installed and I am about to lose my mind, I'm way out of my element here. Please can some one help me before I fall to pieces. Here's what I'm trying:

1) Download 1.7.2 source code package found here (I'm using 1.7.2): http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html

2) CD into the php directory.

3) Run "/configure --with-iodbc=shared"

4) Run "make"

5) Copy the ./modules/odbc.so file into MAMP/bin/PHP5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20050922

6) Add "extension=odbc.so" to php.ini

When I restart MAMP Pro, it doesn't show up in phpinfo(). Also, when I check the PHP log, I see:

"[16-Sep-2009 16:14:10] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'odbc.so' in Unknown on line 0"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found no answer to this and have used [Marc Liyanage's](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/) PHP build which has ODBC in it already.  So when I work in this project, I only use MAMP's MySQL.