# ODBC Module in MAMP: Call to undefined function odbc_connect()

Tags: php, macos, odbc, mamp

I spent all day trying to install a ODBC module for my PHP installation in MAMP. After searching for hours, trying, failing and trying again, finally I managed to compile my pdo_odbc.so file and MAMP load it nice (I use [this guide](http://blog.jellystyle.com/post/37099202581/installing-php-extensions-with-mamp) but instead of using pecl I compiled myself with [this instructions](http://verysimple.com/2013/11/05/compile-php-extensions-for-mamp/))

As you can see in this image of my phpinfo(), MAMP recognizes my unixODBC driver.

[image]

But when I use odbc_connect() in my code, I get this error:

> Fatal error:  Call to undefined function odbc_connect() in ...

It seems that, despide MAMP recognizes unixODBC driver, my web app doesn't do it. Do I need to add some extra configuration in my php.ini file?

I don't know if it has something to do about it but I installed unixODBC with Homebrew and was installed in /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc, but in my ./configure command (before compile the ODBC module) I used parameter `--with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC` who looks in my /usr/local folder. I don't know if this can be the cause of the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "pdo_odbc" module is only to work with objects:

```
$dbh= new PDO('odbc:SOURCENAME', 'username', 'password');
```

I compiled php with the "shared" option to create odbc.so module ([Adding ODBC to MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436160/adding-odbc-to-mamp))

```
./configure --with-unixODBC=shared
make

cp modules/odbc.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/

echo "extension=odbc.so" >> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini
```

Comment: I followed those steps but I got this PHP error: `dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/odbc.so, 9): Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: I tried odbc.so in MAMP 3.0.5 and 2.2.
What version of OS X do you use? I use 10.9.3.

Comment: Same version here, 10.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I have avoided using MAMP and sticking with default Apache, etc. and used this PHP install that includes ODBC and it works great.

Note that since 10.10 is out, recent builds may not include ODBC, but this build of PHP has been a life saver.

http://php-osx.liip.ch

Comment: I tried this, but the latest version (5.6.14) does not include ODBC anymore.